# Unexpected spacing on list-item with list-style-position: inside in Internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

http://krill.larvit.se/resihop_dev/ ,right column ordered list.

HTML:

```
<ol class="instructions">
  <li>
    <p>För att hitta samåkningar, klicka på kartan på platsen du vill åka ifrån.</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

What I believe is the relevant CSS:

```
.instructions{
    padding-left: 0;
}
.instructions li{
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    list-style-position: inside;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.instructions li p{
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 360px;
}
```

In internet explorer 9, a large space is added on the right side of the "1". What can I do about this? If possible I would like to keep the html-markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different browsers render slightly differently but I would personally do the following:

```
.instructions li{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 30px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

That will display fairly close in all browsers, and if you want it closer you need to either make the font size of the 1. smaller **or** add a left margin of -XXpx to the paragraph

```
.instructions li p{
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 360px;
    margin-left:-8px;
}
```

Another alternative would be to have the numbers as a CSS sprite + background image on the li.

Comment: I didn't mention it, so your answer is correct to be fair, but I am using border+ background-color on my li:s.

Comment: did you come to a resolve for this? just having a lil think, you could use multiple background images but that is not supported in IE8 and less.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `<p>` tag from inside the `<li>` tag as its a list entry you don't need it, (*what you have done is added a paragraph the list entry*) you then just style the `<ol>` tag and `<li>` tag

Comment: Noticed how the OP said: *"If possible I would like to keep the html-markup."*